# MySQL Add Numbers

Tags: mysql

I have db with company id numbers and employers, now i need to know who is first, second ... employer entered in db. For this I need to add number for each one like this:

```
CompanyID   NameOfEmp       PositionInDB
111         Emp1            1
111         Emp2            2
111         Emp3            3
112         Emp1            1
112         Emp2            2
113         Emp1            1
114         Emp1            1
114         Emp2            2
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? What have you tried, what did not work as expected? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You didnt really ask any question. Whats the problem?

Comment: Emp1, Emp2, etc are strings written exactly Empx or are something different?

Comment: This table structure looks un-normalised to me.

Comment: My question is how to add this numbers without using php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are stored in an undefined order.  In order to define a position, you have to define an order yourself. This example assigns an order based on the name of the employee.  It will number employees alfabetically per company:

```
select  *
,       (
        select  count(*) + 1
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt2.CompanyID = yt1.CompanyID
                and yt2.NameOfEmp < yt1.NameOfEmp
        ) as PositionInDb
from    YourTable yt1
```

Since you're using MySQL, you could also use a variable:

```
set @num  = 1;

select  CompanyID
,       NameOfEmp
,       @num := if(@last_comp = CompanyID, @num + 1, 1) as PositionInDb
,       @last_comp := CompanyID as dummy
from    YourTable
order by
        CompanyID
,       NameOfEmp
```

Variables are fast and easy, but not portable, and most DBA's dislike them.